# Bootstrap 4: Expand search input in mobile navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a navbar with a search input and the dropdown toggle button but the search input seems to be constrained to 200px. See screenshot below, I'm trying to remove the gap between the input and toggle, I've tried w-100 but not having any luck.

```
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>    

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">          
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">             
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/join" class="nav-link">Join</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/login" class="nav-link">Sign In</a></li>             
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBHWe.png

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do here is wrap the search bar and the toggle in their own d-flex div and play around with the width.

I've made a JS fiddle here... https://jsfiddle.net/fatchild/qmc90okb/78/

It looks like this, notice the wrapper around the input and the toggle.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end w-100"> <!-- THIS IS THE ADDITIONAL HTML -->
  <form class="form-inline pr-1 w-100"> <!-- SOME EXTRA STYLING TO MAKE IT WORK -->
    <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  </form>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>   
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">          
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">             
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/join" class="nav-link">Join</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/login" class="nav-link">Sign In</a></li>             
  </ul>
</div>
```

It is worth noting that this is currently only working with smaller screens, so be sure to rearrange the js fiddle to a small screen size and then take it from there.